# How this happens in Flink to cast an object to an interface that do not implement?

Tags: java, casting, apache-flink

As far as I know, casting an object to an interface which the object doesn't implement is not feasible in JAVA.

However, I have found that the FLink source code seems do this kind of casting.
In `package org.apache.flink.client.deployment`, the [code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/d1cb177c91b41a5387814ad60d1799c08caf3ad9/flink-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/deployment/StandaloneClusterDescriptor.java#L46) is:

```java
    @Override
    public ClusterClientProvider<StandaloneClusterId> retrieve(
            StandaloneClusterId standaloneClusterId) throws ClusterRetrieveException {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return new RestClusterClient<>(config, standaloneClusterId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't retrieve standalone cluster", e);
            }
        };
    }
```

In my understanding, this is casting `RestClusterClient<>` to `ClusterClientProvider<StandaloneClusterId>`.

However, the interface `ClusterClientProvider<T>` is not implemented by any Class, which can be found in the [doc-ClusterClientProvider](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/rest/RestClusterClient.html).
And `RestClusterClient` implements interface `ClusterClient<T>`, as shown in [doc-RestClusterClient](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/rest/RestClusterClient.html) and [doc-ClusterClient](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClusterClient.html).

Since the code can run, I am wondering how this kind of casting happens here? And what's more, `ClusterClientProvider` is not implemented by any class, but there is [code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/d1cb177c91b41a5387814ad60d1799c08caf3ad9/flink-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/cli/CliFrontend.java#L1032) actually invokes the method `getClusterClient()` inside `ClusterClientProvider`:

```java
 try (final ClusterDescriptor<ClusterID> clusterDescriptor =
                clusterClientFactory.createClusterDescriptor(effectiveConfiguration)) {
            try (final ClusterClient<ClusterID> clusterClient =
                    clusterDescriptor.retrieve(clusterId).getClusterClient()) {
                clusterAction.runAction(clusterClient, effectiveConfiguration);
            }
        }
```

The method `getClusterClient()` never has any implementation except in one test file, as shown in the [screenshot: getClusterClient Present in 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPpal.png), so how could this run without errors?

Or am I misunderstanding something?

#### supplementary

I have found the [git logs](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/6825f803de17f87007e0531d82baf14bdbab2fd4) of changing the exact code.
There was no `ClusterClientProvider` in former Flink version, and the return class was exactly `RestClusterClient`.

```java
    public RestClusterClient<StandaloneClusterId> retrieve(
           StandaloneClusterId standaloneClusterId) throws 
           ClusterRetrieveException {
        ...
    }
```

Thank @xerx593 for reminding me of the *Functional Interface*, and I have found some [code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/d1cb177c91b41a5387814ad60d1799c08caf3ad9/flink-clients/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/client/cli/util/DummyClusterDescriptor.java#L44) actually use lambda function to return:

```java
    public ClusterClientProvider<T> retrieve(T clusterId) {
        return () -> clusterClient;
    }
```

I am not quite sure how the following code can be kind of lambda function.

```java
return new RestClusterClient<>(config, standaloneClusterId);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi & Welcome to [so]! :) Might it be a "functional interface"!?;) So it could be "implemented" by any `() -> ...` (lambda expression)!?

Comment: [`ClusterClientProvider<T>`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClusterClientProvider.java) is one! And in fact the(flink) method doesn't return a `RestClusterClient` but a (empty args) "function" of (producing) it!;)

Comment: (jdk17) https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

Comment: Thanks lot! Since I am kind of newbie for both java and Flink, I just ignored the `@Internal` annotation.
I have read the docs and had a basic understanding of **functional interface**.    
But I still have some trouble in understanding "return a empty args function of producing it", I believe there is no lambda function here, so how this "functional interface" works?   
Besides, Also, I added the problem description.  
Again, Thanks for this, and sincerely look forward to your further help if possible.